# Android setContentView and computing

Tags: android, android-progressbar, setcontentview

The first activity of my application is checking the database and upgrading it if needed.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(getThemeFromPreferences(this));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Test et remplissage de la BDD
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.firstProgressBar);
    DatabaseFeeder.testAndFeed(this, progressBar);
    //Launch welcoming activity
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AccueilActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

The DatabaseFeeder.testAndFeed static method is a little slow because it reads from assets, so it can take like 5 secs to fill the database.

Problem is : the contentView is not set before the feeder is finished !
My activity is all blank for 5 seconds and then pop as my content view, including fully filled progressbar.

Why is that so ?

Comment: Try accessing the progressbar inside oncreate itself instead in the onResume. Just dismiss it inside onResume.

Comment: Already tried and doesn't work, also tried onStart(). There is no dismiss, it is not a progressDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run following code in an async task:

```
 DatabaseFeeder.testAndFeed(this, progressBar);
```

this will keep applications main thread free for rendering required views.
also, it is always a good idea to separate long-running operations from  main thread of application.

Comment: I thought it could be a thread question. Could you explain the reasons behind ? And by chance, isn't there any way to say "render view and then do others things" ?

Comment: this is because you are blocking applications main thread. function `setcontentView()` returns immediately as system will be inflating the view on a separate  thread. this thread is not able to post back the result to main thread as it is blocked by your long running DB operation. if you perform your DB operation on a separate thread using `AsyncTask` main thread will be free to handle other important tasks.

Comment: OK, great explanation! But how can I make my DatabaseFeeder call the publishProgress of the Asyntktask ?

Comment: in your `doInBackground` you can call `publishProgress` as per your need. it totally depends on what you are doing in `testAndFeed` method.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple ,call one Asynctask inside your onCreate() menthod  for your database operation , and inside onPostExecute() , update your UI and dismiss progress dialog .

> Reason behind is that , you are performing UI updets in your **MainThread** ,when ever your all operations will done, you are trying to update your **UI** .
>   Database operation should be perform inside background or separate thread ,so it can not effect your main UI thread while performing your operation.